# AWSELB cookie generated though we are using application based session affinity

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-elb

In my application I have front end server and a back end server. Over both the server we have an ELB. In front end ELB we are trying to achieve session affinity using application cookie and in the back end ELB trying to achieve Session Affinity using AWSELB cookie

In the browser I saw whenever I make a new request this "AWSELB" cookie value get changed.
After some debugging I found out that AWSELB cookie is generated by both the server.Due to this my AWSELB cookie value of backend is overridden by the front-end AWSELB cookie.

Can someone please let me know how can I resolve the problem.

Comment: Are you trying to generate a cookie named `AWSELB`  on the back-end?

Comment: If I am using application based cookie stickiness on both front end and backend then also this AWSELB is generated.